# 4 centered and equalsize div + top right bottom link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a 4 column (almost) centered html as a presentation of my website, now I want to add a new div with link floating in the bottom right part of the page, my problem is the element is entering as a new column and center is not correct or getting bad position:

```
.init {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top 0px;
    bottom 0px;
    float: right;
    background: yellow;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: right;
    color: red;
}
```

Here is a fiddle where you can see the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/0rtvcnon/1/

Basically my question is how to center 4 columns AND put the ENTER link floating in the bottom rigth... Something like this

[image]

PS: I use percentage and margin to center columns but if there is a better way I can change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.init {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;
   background: yellow;
   margin-left: 15px;
   font-weight: 700;
   text-align: right;
   color: red;
}
```

Here's a link to the updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/0rtvcnon/2/

```css
html, body {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto auto;
    padding-left:1%;
    
    background: yellow;
    font: normal 16px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.bar {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right:2%;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    color: yellow;
}



.init {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;
    background: yellow;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: right;
    color: red;
}

::-moz-selection {
    color: yellow;
    background: red;
}

::selection {
    color: yellow;
    background: red;
}

p.numbers {
    font-size: 5em;
}

p.meta, p.strings {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 4.5em;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="bar">
    <p id="d" class="numbers">00</p><br>
    <p class="strings">D</p><br>
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <p id="h" class="numbers">00</p><br>
    <p class="strings">H</p><br>
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <p id="m" class="numbers">00</p><br>
    <p class="strings">M</p><br>
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <p id="s" class="numbers">00</p><br>
    <p class="strings">S</p><br>
</div>
<div class="init">
    <div class="z">ENTRA</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: almost this, there is a way to totally center the 4 red columns?

Comment: well now it seems to be centered. check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display: flex` to the parent to put them in a flex `row` then use `align-items: flex-end` to align everything to the bottom and remove `height: 100%` from `.init` so it moves to the bottom. I would also use `flex-basis` for the width on `.bar`

```css
html, body {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal 16px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.bar {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    background: red;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    color: yellow;
}
.bar:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.init {
    background: yellow;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: right;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: calc(100% + 15px);
}

::-moz-selection {
    color: yellow;
    background: red;
}

::selection {
    color: yellow;
    background: red;
}

p.numbers {
    font-size: 5em;
}

p.meta, p.strings {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 4.5em;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="bar">
    <p id="d" class="numbers">00</p><br>
    <p class="strings">D</p><br>
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <p id="h" class="numbers">00</p><br>
    <p class="strings">H</p><br>
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <p id="m" class="numbers">00</p><br>
    <p class="strings">M</p><br>
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <p id="s" class="numbers">00</p><br>
    <p class="strings">S</p><br>
</div>
<div class="init">
    <div class="z">ENTRA</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! is almost this ¿how can I totally center the red columns (there are some extra pixels at left) and `ENTRA` text aligned to right?

Comment: now i don't get the columns full size https://jsfiddle.net/0rtvcnon/3/ ....